# Create instance in specific subnet and security group cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to launch instance using cfn template.The instance needs to be launched on a specific existing subnet and also in a security group created in template.

I have the following parameter to get list with subnets:

```
"Subnet": {
  "Description": "Subnet to put Instance",
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
},
```

I have the following reosurce to create security group:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enables access to instance by port 80",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "80",
            "ToPort": "80",
            "CidrIp": {
              "Ref": "ClientCIDR"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

And I have the following resource to create instance:

```
"WebServer": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    "IamInstanceProfile": "access-profile",
    "SecurityGroupIds": [
      { "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "InstanceSecurityGroup",
          "GroupId"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "SubnetId": {
      "Ref": "Subnet"
    },
```

When i'm trying to create instance and choose existing subnet a got the following error:

```
Security group sg-**** and subnet subnet-**** belong to different networks.
```

Please help to solve this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS::EC2::Subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html) your are adding to the [AWS::EC2::Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) is in a different [AWS::EC2::VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html) to the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html).

When creating your `InstanceSecurityGroup` Resource you should use the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) `VpcId` property to create the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) in a particular [AWS::EC2::VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html). The documentation for this property states

> `VpcId`
>
> The physical ID of the VPC. Can be obtained by using a reference
>   to an AWS::EC2::VPC, such as: { "Ref" : "myVPC" }.
>
> For more information about using the Ref function, see Ref.
>
> Required: Yes, for VPC security groups

Your account uses EC2-VPC, you can only omit the `VpcId` parameter if you are using ec2-classic, [here are the differences](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#VPC_Security_Group_Differences) between ec2-classic and ec2-vpc.

Cloud Formation Templates can accept the AWS Specific [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#d0e14711) Type `AWS::EC2::VPC::Id` eg

```json
"VPCId": {
    "Type":  "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
    "Description": "The VPC Id to where this instance is being created"
}
```

and this [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#d0e14711) can then use the intrinsic [Ref function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) to reference the `VPCId` Parameter in the [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html)

```json
"InstanceSecurityGroup": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enables access to instance by port 80",
        "VPCId": {
            "Ref": "VPCId"
        },
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": "80",
                "ToPort": "80",
                "CidrIp": {
                    "Ref": "ClientCIDR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```